# Ler um valor dentro de um JSON complexo em C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net, newtonsoft

Bom dia pessoal! Sou novo em C# e estou com uma dificuldade em pegar um valor dentro de um Json complexo. O Json é esse:

```
 {
  "id": "58e50b82-50b1-4f29-a2e8-a9a544013255",
  "timestamp": "2018-06-20T18:00:12.935Z",
  "lang": "pt-br",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "me conte uma novidade",
    "action": "",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "news": "novidade"
    }
}
```

Até o momento eu consigo coletar apenas os 3 primeiros dados do Json (id, timestamp e lang) com o seguinte codigo:

Classe da API:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("consumindoApi")]
public HttpResponseMessage DirecionarResposta(Dialogflow dialogflow)
{
  try
  {
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,  
                    @"ID: " + dialogflow.id + 
                    ". Idioma: " + dialogflow.lang + 
                    ". ID da Sessão: " + dialogflow.sessionId + 
                    ". Horario da mensagem: " + dialogflow.timestamp);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e.Message);
   }
 }
```

Classe model que uso para mapear o Json:

```
public class Dialogflow
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
        public string lang { get; set; }
        public string sessionId { get; set; }
        public string result { get; set; }
    }
```

Eu utilizo o Newtonsoft para fazer essa manipulação, mas como sou novo no pedaço, não consigo coletar os dados dentro da lista `result` e `parameters`. 
Como eu faria pra conseguir coletar os valores dos campos dentro dessas duas listas?

Comment: Você deve criar outro objeto para `result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`result` é um outro objeto, não pode ser `string`. Além disso, `parameters` também é um objeto. A estrutura seria assim:

```
public class Parameters
{
    public string news { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string resolvedQuery { get; set; }
    public string action { get; set; }
    public bool actionIncomplete { get; set; }
    public Parameters parameters { get; set; }
}

public class Dialogflow
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}
```

Também é possível fazer sem criar as classes, usando `dynamic`, desse jeito:

```
 dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Veja o exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3UnSgD

Mais sobre `dynamic`: [csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic)

Comment: Certo, então na controler eu teria que chamar o parametro dessa forma?

List<Result> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Result>>() e 
List<Parameters> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Parameters>>()

Comment: Não precisa, como o objeto é um só, bastaria converter para `Dialogflow`:  `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dialogflow>(json)`;

Comment: Agora se vier uma lista, sim seria `<List<Dialogflow>>`

Comment: Entendi, no caso esse valor json seria uma variavel do método para o recebimento da string? 

DirecionarResposta(String json){...}

Comment: Isso mesmo. Também é possível fazer sem criar as classes, usando `dynamic`, desse jeito: `dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`
Vou colocar na resposta

Comment: Caramba, que massa! Show de bola cara, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79348/discussion-between-bruno-henrique-gaignoux-gomes-and-ricardo-pontual).